# Count a specified digit surrounding a position in a typescript array?

Tags: html, reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks

(Using Typescript if that helps)
i want to basically find out how many 2's (literal digit 2) are surrounding a certain position in an array. i have a function that passes in the position, param 1 - row, param 2 - column. Also the array is a 10x10 state grid filled with 0's, 2s are added later in code to represent the bombs:

```
const [grid, setGrid] = useState(() => {
    // create the board - reference (grid) - set (setGrid)
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const row = Array(10).fill(0);
      rows.push(row);
    }
    return rows;
  });
```

i was expecting the number returned to be the number of 2's however often that wasnt the case around the edges of the array, i think the middle was mostly fine though?

i tried something like this, making sure that the square i checked was within the bounds of the array however often the edges numbers were off, sometimes not counting a 2 or missing all completely?

function : comments indicate square im checking such as Top Middle, Bottom Left, etc.

```
function countBombsNearBy(rowIndex: number, colIndex: number): number {
    let count = 0;
    if (rowIndex - 1 >= 0) {
      if (grid[rowIndex - 1][colIndex] === 2) {
        // TM
        count += 1;
      }
      if (colIndex - 1 >= 0) {
        if (grid[rowIndex - 1][colIndex - 1] === 2) {
          // TL
          count += 1;
        }
        if (grid[rowIndex][colIndex - 1] === 2) {
          // ML
          count += 1;
        }
      }
      if (colIndex + 1 <= 9) {
        if (grid[rowIndex - 1][colIndex + 1] === 2) {
          // TR
          count += 1;
        }
        if (grid[rowIndex][colIndex + 1] === 2) {
          // MR
          count += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (rowIndex + 1 <= 9) {
      if (grid[rowIndex + 1][colIndex] === 2) {
        // BM
        count += 1;
      }
      if (colIndex - 1 >= 0) {
        if (grid[rowIndex + 1][colIndex - 1] === 2) {
          count += 1;
        }
      }
      if (colIndex + 1 <= 9) {
        if (grid[rowIndex + 1][colIndex + 1] === 2) {
          count += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDAlzm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the neighbors and then filter them by value. Grab all the surrounding neighbors using a loop. I added a default `radius` parameter of `1`. You could adjust this to search further out.

```
function getNeighbors<T>(
  rowIndex: number,
  colIndex: number,
  source: Array<T>[],
  radius: number = 1,
): Array<T> {
  const neighbors: T[] = [];
  for (let r = -radius; r <= radius; r++) {
    const r1 = rowIndex + r;
    if (r1 > -1 && r1 < source.length) {
      for (let c = -radius; c <= radius; c++) {
        const c1 = colIndex + c;
        if (c1 > -1 && c1 < source[r1].length) {
          if (!(r1 === rowIndex && c1 === colIndex)) {
            neighbors.push(source[r1][c1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return neighbors;
}
```

Grab the neighbors (default radius of 1) and filter them by the value `2` and return the length.

```js
const withValue2 = getNeighbors(rowIndex, colIndex, matrix)
  .filter((v) => v === 2)
  .length;
```

You could combine the inner-most nested conditions, but I left them in for clarity:

```js
if (c1 > -1 && c1 < source[r1].length) {
  if (!(r1 === rowIndex && c1 === colIndex)) {
    // ...
```

```js
if (c1 > -1 && c1 < source[r1].length && !(r1 === rowIndex && c1 === colIndex)) {
  // ...
```

It is typically not a good idea to nest conditional blocks, but the function is supposed to be highly coupled. This generally goes against Clean Code and DRY principles, but we are going for efficiency here.

## Working React TS example

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function getNeighbors<T>(
  rowIndex: number,
  colIndex: number,
  source: Array<T>[],
  radius: number = 1,
): Array<T> {
  const neighbors: T[] = [];
  for (let r = -radius; r <= radius; r++) {
    const r1 = rowIndex + r;
    if (r1 > -1 && r1 < source.length) {
      for (let c = -radius; c <= radius; c++) {
        const c1 = colIndex + c;
        if (c1 > -1 && c1 < source[r1].length) {
          if (!(r1 === rowIndex && c1 === colIndex)) {
            neighbors.push(source[r1][c1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return neighbors;
}

function matrixOf<T>(rows: number, cols: number, initialValue: T): T[][] {
  return Array.from({ length: rows }, () =>
    Array.from({ length: cols }, () => initialValue),
  );
}

type NumberMatrix = number[][];

function App() {
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState<NumberMatrix>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialMatrix = matrixOf(10, 10, 0);

    for (let r = 0; r < initialMatrix.length; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < initialMatrix[r].length; c++) {
        if ((r % 2 === 0 && c % 2 === 1) || (r % 2 === 1 && c % 2 === 0)) {
          initialMatrix[r][c] = 2;
        }
      }
    }

    setMatrix(initialMatrix);
  }, []);

  const displayCount = useCallback(
    (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
      const clickTarget: HTMLElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
      const colIndex = +clickTarget.dataset.colIndex!;
      const rowIndex = +clickTarget.dataset.rowIndex!;
      const cellValue = matrix[rowIndex!][colIndex];
      const withValue2 = getNeighbors(rowIndex, colIndex, matrix).filter(
        (v) => v === 2,
      ).length;
      alert(
        `Cell (${colIndex + 1}, ${
          rowIndex + 1
        }) value: ${cellValue} | neighbors(2) = ${withValue2}`,
      );
    },
    [matrix],
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Click on any cell</h1>
      <div className="grid">
        {matrix.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <div className="row" key={`row-${rowIndex}}`}>
            {row.map((col, colIndex) => (
              <div
                className="cell"
                key={`cell-${rowIndex}-${colIndex}}`}
                onClick={displayCount}
                data-row-index={rowIndex}
                data-col-index={colIndex}
              >
                {col}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-starts;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.cell:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: yellow;
  color: yellow;
}
```

I also created a runnable [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-count-matrix-neighbors-3xkhpc).

---

### Further optimizing

I asked ChatGPT to further optimize the `getNeighbors` function and this is what it came up with. As you can see, it opted for eliminating the inner branching and calculated the min/max ahead of time. This is just one of many approaches to this problem.

```
function getNeighbors<T>(
  rowIndex: number,
  colIndex: number,
  source: Array<T>[],
  radius: number = 1,
): Array<T> {
  const neighbors: T[] = [];
  if (!source?.length) return neighbors; // Handle empty source array

  const numRows = source.length;
  const numCols = source[0].length;
  const minRow = Math.max(0, rowIndex - radius);
  const maxRow = Math.min(numRows - 1, rowIndex + radius);
  const minCol = Math.max(0, colIndex - radius);
  const maxCol = Math.min(numCols - 1, colIndex + radius);

  for (let r = minRow; r <= maxRow; r++) {
    for (let c = minCol; c <= maxCol; c++) {
      if (r !== rowIndex || c !== colIndex) {
        neighbors.push(source[r][c]);
      }
    }
  }

  return neighbors;
}
```

I did make one adjustment to the provided code, I changed:

```js
const numRows = source.length;
if (numRows === 0) return neighbors; // Handle empty source array
```

To an inline optional chaining evaluation:

```js
if (!source?.length) return neighbors; // Handle empty source array
// ...
const numRows = source.length;
```

As kelsny mentioned in the comments, you could make this function O(1) if you hard-code the offsets. If you need to check more than just the 8 surrounding neighbors, you could go with the original function that was prescribed. You will have to make sure you filter the resulting neighbor array, if it is derived from an object matrix.

```
function getNeighbors3<T>(
  rowIndex: number,
  colIndex: number,
  source: Array<T>[],
): Array<T> {
  return [
    source[rowIndex - 1]?.[colIndex - 1],
    source[rowIndex - 1]?.[colIndex],
    source[rowIndex - 1]?.[colIndex + 1],
    source[rowIndex]?.[colIndex - 1],
    source[rowIndex]?.[colIndex + 1],
    source[rowIndex + 1]?.[colIndex - 1],
    source[rowIndex + 1]?.[colIndex],
    source[rowIndex + 1]?.[colIndex + 1],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Oof, I'm not sure if the "Further optimizing" part should be removed because it's not technically the entire answer but it *is* Chat GPT content. Anyways, why not just hard code the index offsets for each of the 8 neighbors and check if the offsets lie within the bounds of the matrix? That's O(1) instead of O(m * n). Well, this would require you to use a 1D array instead of a 2D matrix but PERFORMANCE!

Comment: @kelsny I just tried to make it generic so that you could check _n_-hops outward.